# Notepad ++ removing text between delimiters

Tags: notepad++, regex, notepad

I have some lines of text with this structure:

```
TEXT1:TEXT2:TEXT3
```

I only need `TEXT1:TEXT3` joined together. I want to remove the `TEXT2` value.

I have tried many options to try sorting them but nothing I found worked. I tried with this:

[image: Notepad++ regex]

But I lost about 90% of my lines. Only 10% was successfully converted.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try unticking **. matches newline** in your original expression.

Comment: @James Please post that as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck the **. matches new line** option for your original expression to work as otherwise it will find matches across different lines as well.